# I'm not running (submit) form

Tags: php

I'm not running Query 2 (submit) form.
Just refreshes the page.
How can I fix that I get the function "diе();"

```
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['query1'])) {
//working.. next
            ?>
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['query2'])) {
            die("Go die"); //not working, how to fix?
            }
            ?>
            <form method="post">
                ...Query2 (not working)
                <p><input type="submit" value="Query2" name="query2"></p>
            </form>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <form method="post">
                ...Query1 (working)
                <p><input type="submit" value="Query1" name="query1"></p>
```

Comment: chris85, write as correctly.

Comment: @NikitaLidman: How can `query1` *and* `query2` *both* be set?  They're in different forms.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @David I want query2 to execute my code at the click of a button.

Comment: @NikitaLidman: Then this is a simple typo.  You forgot to close the first `if` statement with a `}`.

Comment: @David `</form>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <form method="post">` closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query2` conditional is inside the `query1` conditional so it will never be executed with your current code (because `query1` is not set when `query2` is processed). It either needs to be moved outside, or you need to update your `form` so the `query1` is also set in `form2`. So either:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['query1'])) {
     //working.. next
     if (isset($_POST['query2'])) {
          die("Go die"); //not working, how to fix?
     }
?>
<form method="post">
    ...Query2 (not working)
    <p><input type="submit" value="Query2" name="query2"></p>
    <input type="hidden" value="just so we are set" name="query1">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

(the above approach assumes the `query1` code should be executed everytime) or

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['query1'])) {
     //working.. next
}
if (isset($_POST['query2'])) {
          die("Go die"); //not working, how to fix?
}
if (isset($_POST['query1'])) {
?>
<form method="post">
    ...Query2 (not working)
    <p><input type="submit" value="Query2" name="query2"></p>
    <input type="hidden" value="just so we are set" name="query1">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```